# Is there a way to set iup a spreadsheet that it will just automatically add a new row, and column?

Tags: excel

K.. need some Excel help! Yes, I am being asked to do something else from my weird, off-the-wall boss that is weird, and off-the-wall. Sigh.... So...... here goes....

In Excel... is there a way to have a spreadsheet, made for others to fill in as needed, that if, let's say, all the rows are already filled in when they go to fill something in, they need to add a line or two, more. Is there a way to set it up that it will just automatically add another row for them, since they don't know how to add rows in Excel.... ??? And same with more columns, if needed?

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a table, excel will automatically make a new row or column part of that table as long as the data is input directly below the last row or right of the last column. Is that what you are looking for?